# Ubuntu server drags network speed down to 10Mbps

Tags: ubuntu, router, tomato

I'm running an Ubuntu Server (14.04) on my home network. It acts as a OpenVPN server (Bridged, not routed) and it runs one Virtual Machine (KVM, through a bridged virtual network device (br0)). The VM acquires its IP address from the LAN router. The main server was earlier serving as a DNS server for my LAN using Bind9 but I have switched that off now.

My router is running Tomato and I have checked the network speed through the router on each IP-address and there is no IP that is clogging the speed with some extreme usage. All my devices summed up are all of a sudden using 1200KB/s (~10Mbps).

When I switch my server off the WAN speed bounces back to 100Mbps (my ips' speed) and the LAN to 1Gbps. Turning the server on, letting it go downloading for a few minutes will result in the 10Mbps drop again...

I have no clue why this phenomena occurs, but if someone recognizes this issue please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Please provide a list of internal IPs for each device, interface configurations for each device and a list of network hardware. Also, please provide info on your Openvpn configuration and if, once openvpn is switched off on the server, the issue resolves itself.

Comment: 192.168.0.107 – Laptop
192.168.0.205 – VM

192.16.0.200-210 are open for lease. 

[/etc/network/interfaces](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SZ6qtv9K)

[/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Y1QDHy7h)

The issue does not resolve when the OpenVPN Daemon is off.

Comment: In more detail... output of ifconfig, output of "cat /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf" (with dangerous bits left out). Include subnet masks configured for each device, summary of config for tomato router, test with NC between servers to see if the 10MBps is just limited at the gateway or across the internal subnet as well. The more detail you can give the more likely we are to be able to help you.

Comment: So it is definitely OpenVPN that pulls down the LAN speed. When the speed is really slow I tried by shutting down the OpenVPN service and noticed the speed bump back up again. I already linked the `openvpn.conf` and `interfaces` files. Look at my comment above.

Comment: I really struggle to make sense of that, unless everything is somehow routing link-local stuff to your server first as a router, and once ovpn is up it somehow routes through a tun adapter. Even then it shouldn't do that. Perhaps you could test the speed of your local subnet between two local machines with something like this: https://jbowes.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/measuring-network-speeds-with-netcat-and-dd/

Comment: Have you verified that your MTU is set to 1492 and not 1500 (the default for ethernet)?